# How to keep the same font style when it displayed ?

Tags: vb.net

I really neeeeeed your help 
this what i wrote :

```
Private Sub AevionButton4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AevionButton4.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text += "- " & TextBox1.Text & ", " & TextBox2.Text & ". " & TextBox3.Text & ". " & TextBox4.Text & ". " & TextBox5.Text & ". " & TextBox9.Text & ", " & TextBox10.Text & "."
End Sub
```

What I want is to make TextBox2 content remains *italic* and the others textboxes regular.
I really need you help guys 
thank you a loooot

Comment: In your previously question *Italic fontstyle in textBox becomes regular* you got an answer. Now you are asking a new question. What make you think that someone will give you an answer when you don't even have the courtesy of accepting the previous one! and it is happening too often which drives people away.

Comment: Who told you that this question is related to the previous one ??!! you assume things! and the answers of the previous question i am not obliged to accept them because they did noooooooooot work for me!! and p.s!! instead of writing such words you were asked to help, if you canoot help so dont comment my dear son .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are wanting to make part of a string *Italic* inside of a `RichTextBox` you need to explicitly set the RTF control codes for the string and set the `.RTF` property instead of the `.Text` property. Below is an example

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl{\f0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}  " &
                   "- " &
                   textBox1.Text & ", " &
                   "\i " & textBox2.Text & ". " & "\i0 " &
                   textBox3.Text & ". " &
                   textBox4.Text & ". " &
                   textBox5.Text & ". "
```

If you are doing a lot of this, you will find it much easier to use an external RTF editor such as `WordPad` in Microsoft Windows to create and format the text, save the file and then use a plain text editor such as `Notepad` to extract the parts you are interested in. I find this to be a much easier method to get the text to look exactly the way I want.

Comment: Thank you alot dear JayV , this really worked for me !

Comment: @EdebEducation Glad to hear this solution works for you. Don't forget to accept it as the answer.